# Display decimal part of a double property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, format, double

I have an asp.net application in which i'd to display a double field in a crystal report.

I'd like to display ,for example, `11.22` as `11`

I used the method [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but i got this double `11,00` as result.

So how can i resolve this problem without converting it to an integer?

Comment: What's about `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(YourDouble))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried;

```
Math.Round(11.22)
```

That ought to do what you want although you need to be aware of the rounding rules.

Comment: it still displaying like this `11,00`

Comment: So are you sending , for example, data to the Crystal report that is the equivalent of Math.round(11.22) and it is now being 'displayed' on the report as 11.00.   I'm not really familiar with Crystal reports but it looks as if you may need to format the field as the report is being displayed / printed.

Comment: Yes this exactly the problem

Comment: This is guesswork on my part but presumably you have a field that is typed as a double.  You can perform the round function on that (which with the figure you use as illustration gives 11) but presumably the control in which it is being displayed in the report is typed as a double so you 11 becomes 11.00.  Could you simply type the field on the report as an integer?

Comment: I just found this link which might help you.  No guarantess but it's specific to Crystal reports and might give you a pointer.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1115770.aspx?Crystal+reports+number+formatting+problem+

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
Math.Floor(11.22)
```

Comment: String.Format("{0:0}", 11.22);